# циклы с функциями

Tags: javascript

у меня есть две функции `getDep()` и `getRate()`,
и проверка(цикл), где `getRate()` не должен превышать `getDep()`, в общем `do` срабатывает два раза при вводе большего значения, после чего цикл прерывается, в чем проблема?

```
function getDep() {
  let dep = +prompt('Введите суму депозита');
  return dep;
}

function getRate() {
  let rate = +prompt('Ваша ставка');
  return rate;
}

getDep();
do {
  getRate()
} while (getRate() > getDep());
```

Comment: Во время выполнения цикла `getRate()` выполняется дважды- при проходе в теле цикла и при вычисления условия `while`.

Comment: А как корректно написать проверку? Что б  getRate() выполнялся до тех пор пока не будет меньше getDep()

Comment: Можно просто убрать `getRate()` из тела цикла.